# Custom payment gateway order getPayment returns null

Tags: magento-2.1, payment-gateway

I'm developing a custom payment gateway. The payment flow uses an iframe to process the payment, and the result is sent by a request to a custom URL. I've succeeded in displaying my custom payment method, with the iframe. But when receiving the request notification, and trying to update the order status, I get the following error:

> Call to a member function getMethodInstance() on null in
>   /vendor/magento/module-payment/Observer/SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver.php:24

I'm using PayPal module as reference. I'm using its set-payment-method action. But it seems that when calling:

```
$this->order->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
var_dump($this->order->getPayment());
```

The method returns NULL, and it's needed in the SalesOrderBeforeSaveObserver.

I've also tried using the set-payment-information action, but then I get an error with message "The payment method you requested is not available." in the API response.

I'm using magento 2.1.2

Any help on on how to solve this or which steps should I follow for this kind of integration will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: Sorry, no. We used paypal in the end.